# Mobile Safari - Autofocus not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-safari

On mobile safari on iPhone...

Before I move on and mark this as unresolvable... is there anyway to autofocus an input field once the page loads?  I don't care when the autofocus gets triggered - I just want it to be automatic vs. clicking somewhere.  I've tried js, HTML5, and jQuery = all failed. I know there is 100+ post, from back when.  I just want to make sure there is no way to do this.

```
<input autofocus id="AutoFocusMe" type="text" placeholder="Email Address"/>
```

JS I've tried:

```
$("#AutoFocusMe").focus();
```

...

```
document.getElementById("AutoFocusMe").focus();
```

...

```
    if (!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input"))) 
{document.getElementById("AutoFocusMe").focus(); }
```

and

```
setTimeout(function() {
jQuery('#AutoFocusMe').focus();
}, 500);
```

Add this to the list now...

```
document.getElementById('AutoFocusMe').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

what about just checking if `autofocus` is `undefined` after the window is loaded, making sure all form elements are loaded.

My example runs in codepen debug mode (no iframe)

http://s.codepen.io/jonathan/debug/xwgWKe?

**You need to run this code either on a remote server or local server, not through an iframe through JSfiddle or CodePen**. JSfiddele and CodePen run code within an iframe. My example above runs in Codepen Debug mode. So it doesn't run the code in an iframe. An iframe will block the `autofocus`

```
// wait until all links, inputs, images are loaded
$(window).on("load", function(){

   if(document.createElement("input").autofocus === undefined) {
       $("[autofocus]").filter(":last").focus();
   }

});
```

if `autofocus` attribute is `undefined` you use an attribute selector to give focus to the last input with the `autofocus` attribute.

The reason i used jQuery on() `load` event handler, was to make sure that the event listener fires consistently for cross browser. Since the `window.load` doesn't work consistently cross browser.

Comment: @RooksStrife This does work in a normal server environment. The reason it doesnt work is due to jsfiddle loading in iframe. Here it is working on CodePen in debug mode. CodePen Debug mode runs the code without an iframe. http://s.codepen.io/jonathan/debug/xwgWKe? I also tested on my remote server and it works.